# Passing params in url instead of params object:

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the below `state` where i am passing `params` as like below:

```
.state("state", {
  url: "/edit/",
  params: {'id': null, 'editMode': true},
  templateUrl: 'views/info.html',
  controller: 'Ctrl'
});
```

How can i pass in the url.

```
url: "/edit/?id=''&editMode=true",
```

Comment: %20 is space isn't it?

Comment: No space required. The value is null for id, not space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
url: "/edit/?id=&editMode=true",
```

Comment: this will be undefined rather than space

Comment: @SoluableNonagon, if user wants to pass "null" value, this is perfect. It seems to me that he does not want to pass a space...

Comment: I guess, I'm seeing empty string in the url but that's an odd request

Comment: @SoluableNonagon, the "empty string" in the url was an example of what he was trying to do in my opinion :) nothing else

Comment: Can i pass like this... url: "/edit/:id&editMode=true",

Comment: @Shane, is it a question? or is that the solution you found?

Comment: well, usually parameters are passed in the form I wrote in my answer, not with a ":". Anyway you can try it if you want, but I doubt it will work

Comment: is it mandatory to pass all the params... for instance the id was earlier not passed like this... but via form... can i pass only editMode alone..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121852/discussion-between-ddb-and-shane).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to compose the params before it enters in the function and append it to the url. You can do a for to make the append in the url_param. This way you will pass all the keys in the param variable.

```
params = {'id': null, 'editMode': true}
url_params = "?id=" + params['id'] + "&editMode=" + params['editMode']
.state("state", {
  url: "/edit/" + url_params,
  templateUrl: 'views/info.html',
  controller: 'Ctrl'
});
```